# SDK location not found

Tags: android-studio, react-native

am new in using react native. 
I install android studio , nodejs , npm . 
Then i connect my device to run the app.When running it i get this  error 
[image]

could anyone help me How  to fix sdk  location in my app ? 
ps: am using linux mint as OS .

Thanks for help

Comment: What is unclear with the message you are seeing?

Comment: normally how can i fix sdk location in the project

Comment: even i don"t find local.properties file !!!

Comment: set env var as clearly mentioned in message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is your first build you must define %ANDROID_HOME% path first in the "Environment Variables"

1. Copy path to your sdk folder

[image: Incase you forgot the sdk path]

2. Open System Properties\Advanced\Environment Variables (search for keyword "environment" for shortcut)

[image]

3. Press "New" in "User variables..." panel
4. Type "ANDROID_HOME" in "variable name" and paste your SDK path --> press Ok

[image]